# Invalid argument in IE

Tags: javascript

I love IE :)

OK, so I've downloaded a scrip called TinySlidshow (http://www.leigeber.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/) works perfectly in FF then I tried IE and boom got an invalid argument error on like 160.

Here is line 160 compressed which is what it looks like by default.

```
if(oh==h){clearInterval(e.si)}else{if(oh!=h){e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'}}
```

I broke it up so I could find exactly what it was and it came down to this line:

```
e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'
```

The line above is quite a few adding/dividing and multiplying on one line so I broke that up so my ocde looked a little like this:

```
e.style.height = new_hight + 'px'
```

But it still gave me the error on the line above. I tried putting a semi-colon on the end and it didn't work either...

The script is located here at the moment:

http://www.romarkdesign.com.au/portfolio2.html

Any ideas what I need to change to make IE work?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether some parameter that's supposed to be a number is ending up being a NaN in IE?  There are some situations where Firefox will give you a numeric value when you ask for "height" or "width", but IE just gives you "auto" or something like that.

Comment: Don't believe the line numbers ie gives you.

Comment: You... you... you LOVE IE?!... Oh. Sarcasm. Got it.

Comment: Please correct your spelling, at least in your code (hight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same prob here. After watching it go through the debugger a few times, I noticed the pattern of the height being set to '-1px' whenever the error popped up.

I may have fixed it...but it *is* IE and prone to flying off the handle in spite of my good intentions.

You need to add "if(oh<2){oh=2};" after the opening bracket of the if(oh!=h) statement.

Change:

```
    if(oh==h){clearInterval(e.si)}else{if(oh!=h){e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'}}
```

to:

```
    if(oh==h){clearInterval(e.si)}else{if(oh!=h){if(oh<2){oh=2};e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'}}
```

The theory here is that TINY doesn't like negative 'px' values, so I set oh to 2 if it is less than 2 coming into the problem statement. This forces the statement to evaluate to 1 at it's lowest value. '1px' seems to make TINY happy in IE...so far.